# using a switch statement to see which 'bin' a number falls into

Tags: c, switch-statement

lets say i have a bunch of bins, each of which holds a range of numbers. an example is:

```
bin 1: 0-8
bin 2: 9-16
bin 3: 17-24
etc
```

is there a way to use a switch statement to figure out which bin a number belongs to? i'm trying to figure out how to make cases reflect that a number is within a range, but they don't seem to be 'constant expressions' so i'm not sure it's possible..

**edit**

I should probably be more accurate; my bins are powers of two...

```
bin 1: 0 to 2^3
bin 2: 2^3 + 1 to 2^4
bin 3: 2^4 + 1 to 2^5
etc
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use ranges for `case` labels in C - only single (constant-expression) values.

If the ranges are small, like your example, then you can do this:

```
switch (value)
{
    case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8:
    bin = 1;
    break;

    case 9: case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16:
    bin = 2;
    break;

    case 17: case 18: case 19: case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24:
    bin = 3;
    break;

    default:
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a lookup table:

```
static const int val_bin[] = {
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, /* 0 to 8 */
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, /* 9 to 16 */
    3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 /* 17 to 24 */
};

bin = val_bin[value];
```

Or, in some cases, you can determine a simple formula.  Your current example appears to be such a case:

```
bin = 1 + (value - 1 / 8);
```

---

**Response to edit:**

For your updated question, on powers of 2, this is actually quite easy.  You can use the "bit-smearing" technique to munge all values that lie between two powers-of-two into one value (this assumes you are using `unsigned long` for `value`, with a maximum value of `2^32 - 1`):

```
if (value > 0)
    value -= 1; /* This is needed because your specified bins are "off by one" from the natural definitions */

value |= value >> 16;
value |= value >> 8;
value |= value >> 4;
value |= value >> 2;
value |= value >> 1;

switch (value)
{
    case 0x00000000UL: /* 0, 1 */
    case 0x00000001UL: /* 2 */
    case 0x00000003UL: /* 2^1 + 1 ... 2^2 */
    case 0x00000007UL: /* 2^2 + 1 ... 2^3 */
    bin = 1;
    break;

    case 0x0000000fUL: /* 2^3 + 1 ... 2^4 */
    bin = 2;
    break;

    case 0x0000001fUL: /* 2^4 + 1 ... 2^5 */
    bin = 3;
    break;

    /* etc */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cascade them though:

```
case 0:case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: ..... case 8:
    do_something();
    break;
case 9: case 10: ....... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler is GCC, you are lucky. GCC has an extension called [case ranges](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges), that allows you to write your switch like this:

```
switch (value) {
    case 0 ... 8:
        bin = 1;
        break;
    case 9 ... 16:
        bin = 2;
        break;
    /* and so on */
}
```

**It is not standard C!**